# How to install AMD Proprietary Drivers on Manjaro?

Tags: drivers, video, manjaro, fglrx

I'm using Linux Manjaro 0.8.13 on my laptop and want to install proprietary drivers.
Here is what I have:

```
efog# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
```

At first, I've tried to install drivers using "Manjaro Settings Manager" and "Hardware detection". Right-clicked on "video-catalyst", then "Install", rebooted and got black screen without X.

Then I've tried to install it manually. At first I downgraded my xorg-server to version 1.15. Here is all of what I did then:

```
yaourt catalyst-test #conflict with mhwd
yaourt catalyst-total-pxp #conflict with mhwd
sudo mhwd -i pci video-catalyst #ok, but black screen
```

Then I removed `mhwd` with `-Rdd` option and tried to install catalyst again. 
I got this:

```
Building fglrx module for 3.18.15-1-MANJARO kernel ...
Failed!!! Check out log: /var/log/catalyst-install.log
Switch to AMD
Switch to AMD
----------------------------------------------------------------
You can use the tool 'aticonfig' to generate an xorg.conf file.
--------------------- ^^^^^^^^^ --------------------------------
fglrx was added into /etc/modules-load.d/catalyst.conf
----------------------------------------------------------------
    atieventsd (needs acpid pkg) on systemd:
systemctl enable atieventsd
systemctl start atieventsd
----------------------------------------------------------------
For more info and troubleshooting visit:
http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI_Catalyst
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
                ATTENTION!
----------------------------------------------------------------
To enable 'automatic re-compilation while system shutdown/reboot' 
testing feature run these commands as root:
systemctl enable catalyst-hook
systemctl start catalyst-hook

More info here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1255575#p1255575
----------------------------------------------------------------
---------------- I/O BUG ---------------------------------------
There's a bug in fglrx found by lano1106 which generates
great amount of unneeded I/O operations

To activate workaround enable systemd service:
systemctl enable temp-links-catalyst
systemctl start temp-links-catalyst

More infos:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1279977#p1279977
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1280193#p1280193
```

`aticonfig --initial` says: `aticonfig: No supported adapters detected`.

Here is `catalyst-install.log`:

```
--------
2015-06-25 13:10:09
Building fglrx module for 3.18.15-1-MANJARO kernel ...
--------
OsVersion says: SMP=1
file /proc/kallsyms says: SMP=1
Warning:
kernel includes at /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/include not found or incomplete
file: /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/include/linux/autoconf.h

Warning:
kernel includes at /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/include not found or incomplete
file: /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/include/linux/autoconf.h

assuming default: MODVERSIONS=0
Warning:
kernel includes at /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/include not found or incomplete
file: /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/arch/x86/include/asm/compat.h

md5sum: /usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build/Module.symvers: No such file or directory
make: entering directory «/usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build»
make: *** No rule to make target «modules».  Stop.
make: exiting directory «/usr/lib/modules/3.18.15-1-MANJARO/build»
```

Help me please, what should I do? I'm totally new to Arch Linux, was using Ubuntu before.

I have only 1 assumption:

```
efog# uname -a               
Linux efog-pc 3.18.14-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 25 01:26:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And in the `.log` file I see version `3.18.15-1`. 
But I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Here! This should do the trick. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/amdgpu-pro-libgl/ https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencl-amd/ https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vulkan-amdgpu-pro/ https://linuxhint.com/aur_arch_linux/ Install the needed dependencies, and it's a go.

Answer (score 0):

I think that now the recommended one for AMD graphics is the AMDGPU-PRO and not the Catalyst.

If the whmd can't find the proper ones, you can still donwload the Linux ones by searching you model at the webpage: https://www.amd.com/en/support.